# Retrieving data from the web using vba

Tags: vba, excel

Just started using html, reasonably capable in vba but having some problems linking the two.

I have passed a registration to a web site and trying to get the results.
code used so far

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
 Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
  Sub GetVehicleDetails()

  Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
  Dim MyURL As String
  Dim x As Integer
  On Error GoTo Err_Clear
  MyURL = "http://www.1stchoice.co.uk/find-a-part"
  x = 0
  Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
  MyBrowser.Silent = True
  MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
  MyBrowser.Visible = True
  Do
  Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
  HTMLDoc.all.license_plate.Value = "LV11VYT"

  For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button") '("input")
  'Get 2nd button
   If MyHTML_Element.Title = "Continue" Then 'MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    x = x + 1
    If x = 2 Then
    MyHTML_Element.Click
    End If
   End If
  Next
Err_Clear:
  If Err <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  Resume Next
  End If
  End Sub
```

Now I need to wait until page is refreshed and then get the result, but I'm not certain how to pull the result out

Source code is

```
<div id="block_subheader" class="block_editable block_wysiwyg">
<p>Almost there! <strong>TELL US</strong>&nbsp;which parts you need - <strong>ADD&nbsp;</strong>your contact details &amp; receive <strong>No Obligation Quotes</strong><span style="font-weight: normal;">&nbsp;to compare &amp; </span><span style="font-weight: normal;"><strong>Save &pound;&pound;'s!</strong></span></p>                      
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<form id="step3" action="/find-a-part/step-3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="clearfix">
<h2>RENAULT MEGANE (X95) DYNAMIQUE TOMTOM DCI ECO 3 DOOR COUPE 1461cc (2011) DIESEL</h2>
<p><a href="/find-a-part/step-2">Not quite the vehicle you're searching for? Click here to specify the vehicle exactly</a></p>
</div>
```

Trying to get the Renault Megane details

Can anyone help please?

OK I have got past this part but have run into another problem, when the page changes after the button is clicked I need to update the html.document to the new page as when I use it in the code it pulls up the old source code.

I can get it to work but It only works with a message box activating to say what the browser name is.

Any suggestions?

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
 Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub GetVehicleDetails2()

  Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
  Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument, Doc As HTMLDocument
  Dim MyURL As String, Vehicle As String
  Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
  On Error GoTo Err_Clear
  MyURL = "http://www.1stchoice.co.uk/find-a-part"
  x = 0
  'open new explorer
  Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
  MyBrowser.Silent = True
  'navigate to page
  MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
  MyBrowser.Visible = True
  'wait until ready
  Do While MyBrowser.Busy Or _
  MyBrowser.readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
  Loop
  Do
  Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document

    'enter registration in text box
    HTMLDoc.all.license_plate.Value = "LV11VYT"

    'click continue button
    Set MyHTML_Element = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")(1)
    MyHTML_Element.Click
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    'wait until page updated

    Set Doc = MyBrowser.document
    'Application.Wait (Now() + "00:00:05")

    'does not work if you take this out
    MsgBox MyBrowser.FullName

    'find text returned with vehicle details
    For Each MyHTML_Element In Doc.getElementsByTagName("form")
      If MyHTML_Element.ID = "step3" Then
        Vehicle = MyHTML_Element.innerText
        MsgBox Vehicle
      End If
    Next
  'close browser down
 'MyBrowser.Quit

Err_Clear:
  If Err <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  Resume Next
  End If
  End Sub
```

using 2003 or 2007, tried web queries, cant pass value & use continue button.

Comment: Please indicate your version of Excel. Also: did you experiment with wbe queries ? In some cases they would allow to do what you want with little or no programming !

Comment: I meant Excel *web* queries

Comment: +1 for (refreshingly compared to some new posters here) having a decent first pass :)

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to start an argument over extracting an element from HTML using Regex (vs. a parser) but Regex would be an easy way to extract the element you need, as it is well-defined and you only need that element.

You could do something like (and I provide an alternative way just using InStr, that works for your example but if there are lots of results returned at once or syntax changes etc then Regex would be more flexible):

```
Sub blah()

    Dim testStr As String

    'test string you provided in the Question -> substitute it for your HTML return
    testStr = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value

'Method 1: Use a simple Instr (fine for the example you provided, but if different bits you need to search are more complicated then you may need to use Regex instead

    Dim startLocation As Long, endLocation As Long
    Dim extractedText As String

    startLocation = InStr(1, testStr, "<h2>", vbTextCompare)

    If Not startLocation > 0 Then

        Exit Sub 'or move to next or whatever

    Else

        endLocation = InStr(startLocation, testStr, "</h2>", vbTextCompare)

        extractedText = Mid(testStr, startLocation + 4, endLocation - startLocation - 4)

        Debug.Print "Basic InStr method: "; extractedText

    End If

'Method 2: Use Regex

    'more flexible -> reference a Regex engine.
    'This example uses Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    'That engine uses the same syntax as MS JavaScript regex
    'See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx for syntax

    Dim regex As RegExp
    Dim match As match

    Set regex = New RegExp

    With regex

        .Pattern = "(?:<h2>)([\s\S]*?)(?=</h2>)"
        'NB this regex engine does not support lookbehinds :-(
        'so we have to extract the submatched group for what we want
        '(vs. just using Match.Value)
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True

        For Each match In .Execute(testStr)

            Debug.Print "Regex match: "; match.SubMatches.Item(0)

        Next match

    End With

End Sub
```

Output is:

```
Basic InStr method: RENAULT MEGANE (X95) DYNAMIQUE TOMTOM DCI ECO 3 DOOR COUPE 1461cc (2011) DIESEL
Regex match: RENAULT MEGANE (X95) DYNAMIQUE TOMTOM DCI ECO 3 DOOR COUPE 1461cc (2011) DIESEL
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I didn't need to get it from the string of text. I was trying to find out how to get the innertext of the document that showed the string of text. I have sorted that out now, but thanks anyway.