# Fill a web form via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, html

*Intro:* I would like first of all to state that I am not comfortable at all when it comes to "HTML". I have done an exhausted web-search of how to accomplish the below described task. (e.g. [Retrieving data from the web using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034441/retrieving-data-from-the-web-using-vba), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdD2bb4DU6c, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GswfT0Mrr5M )

*Problem:* In summary would like to fill in a website form (about 10^3 times), submit the query and get each result. In order to test it and keep it simple I am testing it for one value. The VBA code that I managed to put together so far is based on what others have done. It opens a new IE window with the desired URL but it does not fill the desired fields with the "test" Permit # (11) and Suffix (R).

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub Test()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "http://www.dwr.state.co.us/wellpermitsearch/"
''open new explorer
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
''navigate to page
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
''wait until ready
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
''enter permit number and suffix in text box
HTMLDoc.all.txtPermit.Value = "11"
HTMLDoc.all.txtPermitSuf.Value = "R"
'# HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtPermit").attribute.Value = "11"
'# HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtPermitSuf").attribute.Value = "R"
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
'# If MyHTML_Element.ID = "txtPermit" Then MyHTML_Element.Value = "11"
'# If MyHTML_Element.ID = "txtPermitSuf" Then MyHTML_Element.Value = "R"
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If

End Sub
```

I have also included some commented code " '# " that are other ways that a friend suggested me that might work. Does anyone have any idea what am I missing???

**Thank you in advance for your help and time! :)**

Comment: `Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` where is variable IE is defined?

Comment: Opps Sorry...  MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Comment: @PanagiotisO. I tested your sub, and it got to the webpage, and the Number field was filled in as '11' and Suffix was 'R'... is this not what you want it to do?

Comment: @bsapaka I neither get the fields filled in nor I get entries at the result table at the webpage.

Comment: @PanagiotisO.  I am using IE 11, what are you using? Not sure if that would be a factor but it might

Comment: @bsapaka I am using IE 9. I will update it and I will comment again if that will work.

Comment: @bsapaka I just updated the IE to 11th version. No luck. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @PanagiotisO. try on a different computer

Comment: @bsapaka You were right! The problem was my organization's pc, not the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your organizations network blocking the traffic

Try a different computer on a different network